# Varnish backend host directly in vcl_recv?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Can I mention backend host directly in vcl_recv?

```
   sub vcl_recv{
       if (req.http.host=="www.yourdomain.com.a-free-cdn.com") {
           set req.http.host = "www.yourdomain.com";
           set req.backend.host = "www.yourdomain.com";
       }
   }
```

If this is not possible, is there an alternate way to do that? Actually, I don't know in advance anything about back-ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I think you are referring to `req.backend`/`req.backend_hint` in `vcl_recv()`, in [Varnish 3](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#backend-declarations) syntax:

```
backend www {
  .host = "www.example.com";
  .port = "http";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host ~ "(?i)^(www.)?example.com$") {
    set req.backend = www;
  }
}
```

And in [Varnish 4](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-backends.html) syntax:

```
backend www {
  .host = "www.example.com";
  .port = "http";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host ~ "(?i)^(www.)?example.com$") {
    set req.backend_hint = www;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't know about backend when writing vcl. I can't write the backend like you mentioned. The backend domain name comes with the request.

Comment: No, you have to define the backends in advance. You can't use varnish as a forward proxy if that's your intention.